C compiler cannot create executables - ERROR on Mac
I am trying to ./configure and then make install a package, but the configure command gives me this error:
C compiler cannot create executables
It suggests me to look over the config.log.
I can not find what could be the problem.
Should I install something in the Anaconda environment?
Here the config.log:
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = alkhwarizmi.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 22.6.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Mon Feb 19 19:48:53 PST 2024; root:xnu-     8796.141.3.704.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
    Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Mon Feb 19 19:48:53 PST 2024; root:xnu-    8796.141.3.704.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 8.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 546 tasks, 1823 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.57, Mach factor: 2.42
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/anaconda3/bin
PATH: /opt/anaconda3/condabin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
PATH: /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
PATH: /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin

## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2224: checking build system type
configure:2238: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
configure:2258: checking host system type
configure:2271: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
configure:2301: checking for x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-gcc
configure:2328: result: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
configure:2597: checking for C compiler version
configure:2606: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang --version >&5
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/anaconda3/bin
configure:2617: $? = 0
configure:2606: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -v >&5
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/anaconda3/bin
configure:2617: $? = 0
configure:2606: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -V >&5
clang-14: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-14: error: no input files
configure:2617: $? = 1
configure:2606: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -qversion >&5
clang-14: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang-14: error: no input files
configure:2617: $? = 1
configure:2637: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:2659: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-      vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /opt/anaconda3/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isystem /opt/anaconda3/include -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/opt/anaconda3/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file         '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture     x86_64
clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:2663: $? = 1
configure:2701: result: no
configure: failed program was:

| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2706: error: in `/Users/elena/Downloads/fac-master':
configure:2708: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Thank you for your help.

read the log and you will see that your configure step does not work properly

Does this answer your question? ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file
